# Dirty flag not appearing in kendo grid when editing incell mode

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid in the detail row that is editable, and when I edit a cell and leave it there is no dirty flag. I thought that maybe it was hidden, so I added a button to get all dirty cells and wasn't getting in returned.

I looked at the kendo forums and found a solution to add dirty flags but I can't get it working and not sure where the issue is, I must be overlooking something but not sure what it could be, one thing I have noticed is that the change event isn't firing.

I could use a fresh pair of eyes to point out what I am missing

```js
//#region Data

var dropdownData = [{
    "CatalogID": 1,
    "NameVersion": "Catalog1"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 2,
    "NameVersion": "Catalog2"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 3,
    "NameVersion": "Catalog3"
  },
  {
    "CatalogID": 4,
    "NameVersion": "Catalog4"
  },
];

var gridData = [{
    "RoomID": 1,
    "RoomName": "Room 1",
    "Areas": [{
      "id": 1,
      "AreaName": "Area 1"
    }, {
      "id": 10,
      "AreaName": "Area 10"
    }]
  },
  {
    "RoomID": 2,
    "RoomName": "Room 2",
    "Areas": [{
      "id": 2,
      "AreaName": "Area 2"
    }, {
      "id": 20,
      "AreaName": "Area 20"
    }]
  },
  {
    "RoomID": 3,
    "RoomName": "Room 3",
    "Areas": [{
      "id": 3,
      "AreaName": "Area 3"
    }, {
      "id": 30,
      "AreaName": "Area 30"
    }, {
      "id": 35,
      "AreaName": "Area 35"
    }]
  },
  {
    "RoomID": 4,
    "RoomName": "Room 4",
    "Areas": [{
      "id": 4,
      "AreaName": "Area 4"
    }, {
      "id": 40,
      "AreaName": "Area 40"
    }]
  }
];

//#endregion

(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', () => {
    var grid = $('.eagClass').data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var dirty = $.grep(data, function(item) {
      return item.dirty
    });

    console.log("dirty", dirty);
  });

  ShowTabEditor(gridData);
})();

function ShowTabEditor(data) {
  $('#TabEditor').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: data
    },
    schema: {
      model: "RoomID",
      fields: {
        RoomID: {
          editable: false,
          hidden: true
        },
        RoomName: {
          editable: false,
          type: "string",
          hidden: false
        },
        AreaCount: {
          editable: false,
          type: "number",
          hidden: false
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "RoomID",
        title: "RoomID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        field: "RoomName",
        title: "RoomName",
        hidden: false
      },
      {
        field: "AreaCount",
        title: "AreaCount",
        hidden: false
      }
    ],
    selectable: "row",
    detailInit: TabEditorDetailInit,
    detailExpand: function(e) {
      this.select(e.detailRow.prev());
      this.collapseRow(this.tbody.find('> tr.k-master-row').not(e.masterRow));
    }
  }).data("kendoGrid");
}

function TabEditorDetailInit(e) {
  $("<div class='eagClass' />").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true,
    selectable: "row",
    filterable: false,
    toolbar: kendo.template($("#EditAreaGridToolbarTemplate").html()),
    schema: {
      model: {
        fields: {
          id: {
            nullable: true
          },
          AreaName: {
            nullable: true,
            editable: true
          },
          Catalog: {
            editable: false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        title: "id",
        field: "id",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='#=id #' />",
        width: "10px"
      }, {
        field: "AreaName",
        title: "Area Name",
        width: "20px",
        template: "#=dirtyField(data,AreaName) # #:AreaName#"
      }, {
        title: "Catalog",
        field: "Catalog",
        template: "<input class='edit-area-catalog-dropdown' type='text' />",
        width: "40px",
        editable: false
      }
    ],
    editable: {
      mode: "incell",
      confirmation: false
    },
    dataSource: {
      data: e.data.Areas
    },
    batch: true,
    pageSize: 100,

    dataBound: function(w) {
      abindCatalogDropDownInCellProcess(e.detailCell);
    },
    change: onChange(e)
  });

  StopCollapsing("#TabEditor");
}

function onChange(e) {
  if (e.action == "itemchange") {
    console.log("in change");
    e.items[0].dirtyFields = e.items[0].dirtyFields || {};
    e.items[0].dirtyFields[e.field] = true;
  }
}

function StopCollapsing(grid) {
  var parentGrid = $(grid).data("kendoGrid");
  var expanded = $.map(parentGrid.tbody.children(":has(> .k-hierarchy-cell .k-i-collapse)"), function(row) {
    return $(row).data("uid");
  });

  parentGrid.one("dataBound", function() {
    parentGrid.expandRow(parentGrid.tbody.children().filter(function(idx, row) {
      return $.inArray($(row).data("uid"), expanded) >= 0;
    }));
  });
}

function dirtyField(data, fieldName) {
  var hasClass = $("[data-uid=" + data.uid + "]").find(".k-dirty-cell").length < 1;
  if (data.dirty && data.dirtyFields[fieldName] && hasClass) {
    return "<span class='k-dirty'></span>"
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

function abindCatalogDropDownInCellProcess(cell) {
  cell.find("td input.edit-area-catalog-dropdown").each(function() {
    $(this).kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "NameVersion",
      dataValueField: "CatalogID",
      optionLabel: "Select Catalog...",
      dataSource: {
        transport: {
          read: function(options) {
            if (dropdownData.length > 0) {
              options.success(dropdownData);
              return;
            }
            options.success(dropdownData);
          }
        }
      },
      select: function(e) {
        var grid = $("#TabEditor").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var drpDataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.620/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="EditAreaGridToolbarTemplate">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="btnAddNewArea"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  <button id="btnDeleteArea" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
</script>

<button id="btn" class="btn btn-success">Get dirty rows</button>
<div id="TabEditor"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two issues that you have and fixed them. Your custom get button still doesn't work like it should not sure why.
But here are the other two fixes.

Your change event is in the wrong place, just move it to datasource, like this:

```
dataSource: {
  data: e.data.Areas,
  change: function(event)
         { onChange(event);}
},
```

Also use an other name then 'e', because e is passed from the other function. In my case I use event so it will be an event for that context of datasource and datagrid. This will fire the change event.

Also your class if statement is wrong it should be like this:

```
function dirtyField(data, fieldName) {
  //var hasClass = $("[data-uid=" + data.uid + "]").find(".k-dirty-cell").length < 1;
  if (data.dirtyFields && data.dirtyFields[fieldName]) {
    return "<span class='k-dirty'></span>"
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achive with the hasClass. So I just cut it out of the if block. But if you need it, the figure out why it is always false, and will never add the dirty class. Also there is no data.dirty only data.dirtyFields which you need to check.

Also a working Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/adOSogix

Cheers,